# how to compare rows and identify the duplicate values in a column by grouping other columns in scala databricks

Tags: scala, databricks

[image]

I want to identify the Yellow rows because they are same date and belong to same groupid and same identifier1. 
The green one are the right ones because they belong to different groupid and different identifier1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala has the `dropDuplicates` function for dropping duplicates based on the columns that you provide.  A simple example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq (
  ( 1, 1, 1234, "12010", "null"   ),
  ( 1, 2, 1234, "22201", "null"   ),
  ( 2, 1, 2345, "12011", "null"   ),
  ( 2, 2, 2345, "12011", "null"   ),
  ( 2, 3, 2345, "32011", "yellow" ),
  ( 2, 4, 2345, "32011", "yellow" ),
  ( 3, 1, 3456, "4012   ", "null"   ),
  ( 3, 2, 3456, "52012", "green"  ),
  ( 4, 1, 4567, "52012", "green"  ),
  ( 4, 2, 4567, "52013", "null"   )
)
  .toDF( "identifier1", "identifier2", "groupid", "date", "colour" )

//df.show

// Drop the duplicates based on date and identifier1 columns
df
  .dropDuplicates(Seq("date", "identifier1"))
  .show
```

My results:

[image: results]

I would say it's not 100% clear from your example exactly what is required but hopefully that proves a useful starting point.  Read more about `dropDuplicates` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#dropDuplicates()).